# angular/material 6 menu only opens in top left

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have upgraded to `angular@6.0.2`, `angular/material@6.0.2`, `cli@6.0.3` My working apps have the menus now opening in the upper left instead of tied to the trigger.
I ran the default `cli` install and added this to `app.component.html`

```
<button mat-fab color="primary"  [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu class="myMenu" #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

`MatMenuModule` is imported. The only way i have been able to move the open menu is by through this `css` which is a terrible kludge.

```
.myMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(figure out using nnvh - nnpx);
    left: calc(figure out using nnvw - nnpx);
}
```

the only issue is the position of the menu - all of this worked just fine `@5.x.x`. Now my working apps appear broken.

Comment: lol i have similar issue like you write solution if you fixed it

Comment: Did you find something about this problem? We've just updated our app and now we have this problem!!

Comment: anyone found the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to use also the latest material CSS file that is provided in the material/ prebuilt-themes directory as following class seems to be needed now to make the menu work properly:

```
.cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
min-width: 1px;
min-height: 1px;}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, I bumped @angular/cli to @6.0.5 (just in case), added @angular/material & @angular/cli@latest (6.1.0). ran ng serve on the demo project and added a trivial menu - it now opens up exactly where it should. I spent a lot of time fooling with this, even redoing working menu to a *ngFor list and that was a PITA. This is a good lesson in NOT UPDATING when you have a working app...

Comment: Yup, I missed this step in my upgrade to Angular 6.  My app has a custom theme file, so rebuilding with node-sass to generate a new app.theme.css injected the new style above out of @angular/material/theming and my MatMenus now work!

Comment: I am still facing this issue with @angular/cli - 6.1.2 and @angular/material - 6.4.7

Answer (score 0):

For me I needed to add this class to not have this problem :

```
.cdk-overlay-pane {
   position: absolute;
}
```